# Rearrange column order in Sqlyog

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlyog

Is it possible to rearrange a table's column order in SQL yog?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.
Table / More Table Operations / Reorder Columns  (ctrl shift r)

Answer (score 0):

Column order is irrelevant to a database, so there isn't any benefit beyond readability to reorganizing column order.

The only means of reordering a tables columns is to:

1. Rename the current table to something else, like [tablename]_ORIG.  A database won't allow identically named tables
2. Create a new table with the column order you desire
3. Copy the data from the old table into the new one
4. Delete the old table